# TFS mac eclipse plugin - Can't connect to server, error 403

Tags: eclipse, macos, tfs, azure-devops, tee

I installed the Team Explorer Everywhere Eclipse (Kepler) Plugin but when I try to connect to the server i get this message:

> The SOAP endpoint https://vsas.myurl.com/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted.  HTTP status: 403

1st time I tried to connect, it asked me for my user and password, after that it never asked me again, but I want to try with different user/pass and I cant find where I can change that.

I'm using OS Mavericks, and I didn´t find any credential related in the keychain utility.

Thank you!

Edit: My user is out of license, but I have another user that is with a valid license. I would like to try with other user/pass but I don't know where to change that.

Comment: HTTP 403 does not indicate that you have a username/password problem.  Are you sure your URL is correct?  Did you include the `tfs` suffix, which is commonly required?  Did you specify the collection?

Comment: The URL is correct, other guys are using it in their visual basic. I tried with the `tfs` suffix but nothing changed, the same as specifying the collection.

Comment: Do you need to use a proxy server to get out of your network? Is the server on your local network and you shouldn't be using a proxy server? Does changing the proxy setting in Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections (to "direct") change this behavior?

Comment: I don't need a proxy, the config is set to direct. I added some info to the main question.

Comment: I see; if you want to change the username/password, this is indeed stored in your login keychain.

Comment: I tried to find it in the keychain utility, but I couldn't. There's nothing related to eclipse, or visual, or tfs, tee, teamfoundation, microsoft, the server address... I don't know where else look for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I uninstall the plugin, logout from TFS Website, re-install the plugin, enter a new username and password when prompted and that was the solution, everything is working fine now.